# Can you define <=> in Ruby and then have ==, >, <, >=, and <= defined automatically?

Tags: ruby, mixins, spacecraft-operator

Here's part of my `Note` class:

```
class Note
  attr_accessor :semitones, :letter, :accidental

  def initialize(semitones, letter, accidental = :n)
    @semitones, @letter, @accidental = semitones, letter, accidental
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @semitones <=> other.semitones
  end

  def ==(other)
    @semitones == other.semitones
  end

  def >(other)
    @semitones > other.semitones
  end

  def <(other)
    @semitones < other.semitones
  end
end
```

It seems to me like there should be a module that I could include that could give me my equality and comparison operators based on my `<=>` method. Is there one?

I'm guessing a lot of people run into this kind of problem. How do you usually solve it? (How do you make it DRY?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep just `include Comparable` - the only requirement is to have the spaceship `<=>` method defined.

Comment: ah great! I knew there'd be something, but it was kind of hard to search for. :P Thanks!